HTML5 Video Tag Controls Malfunction with Multiple Videos on the Same Page
I am experiencing an issue where the controls of the HTML5 <video> tag malfunction when there is more than one video on the same page. Specifically, clicking on the controls of one video affects another video, or the controls do not respond as expected.
Chrome version: 125.0.6422.141 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Steps to Reproduce:
Create a simple HTML page with two or more video elements.
Add the controls attribute to each video tag.
Attempt to interact with the controls of each video.
A good example can be seen on the official Mozilla site (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video). Copy the video example at the bottom of the page. If you try to click on "more options," the options will open on the video below, interacting with the first video.
Sample Code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Video Controls Issue</title>
</head>
<body>
<video controls width="250">
  <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" type="video/webm" />

  <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

  Download the
  <a href="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm">WEBM</a>
  or
  <a href="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4">MP4</a>
  video.
</video>
<br/>
<video controls width="250">
  <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm" type="video/webm" />

  <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

  Download the
  <a href="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm">WEBM</a>
  or
  <a href="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4">MP4</a>
  video.
</video>
</body>
</html>


Has anyone encountered similar issues with HTML5 video controls? Are there known workarounds or fixes for this problem?
I expected the controls to open on the top video, not the bottom video.

Apparently this bug has been fixed, its working on Chrome Version 126.0.6478.61 (Official Build) (64-bit).
